# Angular Material AutoComplete, Automatically choose the Distinct Item in List

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material, angular8

We have Distinct, Unique List of Document Numbers, where No document numbers are shown in list twice.

I am trying to make it so Angular Material automatically, selects the distinct one, if its entered in with Copy and Paste .

[image]

Currently, after copying and pasting with Ctrl-C/V , we are using three things: OptionSelected for mouse selection, OptionActivated for Keyboard selection, and OnBlur so when clicking out of textbox, the option will be selection.

I am just curious if Angular Material has any cleaner option, or is this probably the best way with three lines of code ?

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Document Number</mat-label>
  <input type="text"
        matInput
        formControlName="documentNumber"
        (blur)="documentNumberChangeEvent($event)"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto"
  >
  <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" 
    (optionActivated) = "documentNumberChangeEvent($event)"
    (optionSelected)="documentNumberChangeEvent($event)"
  >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be a better way is to listen the [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) `valueChanges` property:

```js
...
@Component(...)
export class AutocompleteSimpleExample {
  readonly documentNumber = new FormControl();
  readonly options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];

  constructor() {
    this.documentNumber.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value);
    });
  }
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6dqt8x)